# return only values in a row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a list of unique ids and values on one sheet in excel as in the image below:

[image]

Is there a way to return only the values in the order they appear (left to right) on a separate sheet/location? For example, I would want to return for ID '1002' the values 35,32,44.. not the blanks. I am then going to turn those values into a Sparkline.

I am using excel 2010, if that makes a difference.

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: First it is best practice to also show exactly your expected output.  A picture being easier to understand than word.  Second it is always better to post the data as text instead of a picture so we can copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(B2 & " " & C2 & " " & D2 & " " & E2 & " " & F2)," ",",")
```

**EDIT**:
**_______________________________________________________________________________**

Hope this is not too late to answer your question.

Lets assume your data is in `Sheet1` as in the image below:

[image]

Now, in Cell `B2` of `Sheet2` enter the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B2:Sheet1!$F2, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B2:Sheet1!$F2), "", COLUMN(Sheet1!$B2:Sheet1!$F2)-MIN(COLUMN(Sheet1!$B2:Sheet1!$F2))+1), COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag this formula across till `Column F` and down till `Row 4` or as required.  This will give you following result.

[image]

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: this works great, but it doesn't format in a way that would allow creation of a sparkline, is it possible to break the output into separate cells?

Answer (score 0):

Based on "[Concatenating Names with Delimiters](http://excel.tips.net/T002173_Concatenating_Names_with_Delimiters.html)" by Allen Wyatt you can use the formula below to achieve the result you wanted.

```
=MID(IF(B2<>"",","&B2,"")&IF(C2<>"",","& C2,"")&IF(D2<>"",","&D2,"")&IF(E2<>"",","&E2,"")&IF(F2<>"",","&F2,""),2,2000)
```

Regards,

Comment: this works great, but it doesn't format in a way that would allow creation of a sparkline, is it possible to break the output into separate cells?