# Take only used cells by row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge Excel spreadsheet with survey results.
For each row there are about 100 columns with possible answers.
Each respondent gave between 3 and 9 answers. 
So it sort of looks like this:
R1: -----x-----x------x-------
R2: --x--x-------x-------xx----
R3: --------x----x---x-------x-
....

Now I want to make it spreadsheet with only used cells. 
Like this:
R1: xxx
R2: xxxxx
R3: xxxx
...

Column titles are not important.

Any suggestions?

Would help me a lot. 
Thanks!

Comment: If you are okay with formula, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800297/return-only-values-in-a-row/36808884#36808884) should help. See **EDIT** in answer.

Comment: just to clarify, is each character in its own cell?

Comment: No the values are strings.
I want to keep the cells and values as they are, but just remove all the blank cells in between (by row).

Comment: @Mrig The formula doesn't seem to work. I'll try to figure out what it does and remake it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in `Sheet1` as

[image]

Then use following formula in any other sheet

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A1:Sheet1!$AE1, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A1:Sheet1!$AE1), "", COLUMN(Sheet1!$A1:Sheet1!$AE1)-MIN(COLUMN(Sheet1!$A1:Sheet1!$AE1))+1), COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then drag/copy this formula across and down as required.

This is how result will look like

[image]

Here formula is using range from `Column A` to `Column AE`

Comment: @M.West - Great you've got a work around on your own. However can you share the error you're getting because this is a working formula I often use.

Answer (score 0):

Since the formula gave an error I just found a "work-around" solution myself.

1. Save spreadsheet as CSV
2. Open CSV in Word
3. Reduce all multiple semicolons to one with replace all function
4. Convert text back to CSV.
5. Solved :)

Thanks anyway for your, much appreciated, help!